# integrals of theta functions on tori

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, theta-functions

Define the function $w(x):= \frac{\theta_2(x)}{\theta_1(x)}$,
where $x$ is a point in Jacobian variety of torus $T^2$,
namely $x$ in the argument means $\int_{P_0}^x \omega$,
$\omega$ being the holomorphic differential
and $P_0$ some base point,
and I left implicit the dependence on period matrix $\tau$ of $T^2$;
$\theta_1$ the odd Riemann theta function for genus $g=1$,
while $\theta_2$ is the one with characteristic $(1/2,0)$.

I want to compute the integral
$$I:= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{T^2} d^2x \int_{T^2 \setminus C(\epsilon,x)} d^2y
\int_{T^2 \setminus \left( C(\epsilon,x)\cup C(\epsilon,y)\right)} d^2z \,
w(x-y) \, w(y-z) \, w(z-x)$$
where I'm removing small disks of radius $\epsilon$ and center $x$ or $y$.
Perhaps the removal of disks is not the only way of computing the integrals, just a tool.

Do you know a simple way to do it?

Comment: what would be the result of $\int_{T^2} d^2 z \ w(y-z) w(z-x)$ and $\int_{C_\epsilon(p)} d^2 z \ w(y-z) w(z-x)$  ?

Comment: @user1952009 I don't know, that's what I'm looking for.